# Install MongoDB with Powershell

Tags: mongodb, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to install mongo with powershell, I am download the mongo exec and config file from s3.

```
Read-S3Object -BucketName cfir-test  -KeyPrefix Tools -Folder c:\ 
msiexec.exe /q /i c:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-2.8.0-rc5-signed.msi INSTALLLOCATION="c:\mongodb" 
md \mongodb\data\db 
md \mongodb\data\log 
md \mongodb\data\journal 
mv C:\mongod.cfg C:\mongodb\ 
start-job -Name installmongo {C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe -config C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg --install} 
net start MongoDB 
start-job {C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe C:\db_constraints.js}
```

The issue is with the `start-job -Name installmongo {C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe -config...`, it seems that the command no running also tried `--quit`

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that Powershell does not execute .exe files unlike a 
   default facility in cmd, you need to add the PATH of your bin 
   folder to environment variables and see if that works out.
2. You'll have to install mongoDB cmdlets for powershell, why not use cmd instead, way more convenient.